# How to exit a process from Window Service in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I have two processes both developed in C#.

One of them is a Windows Service, the other one a normal windows based application.

What I intend to do is to exit the application from Service,

I don't intend to kill it forcibly, which i am able to do. I want to exit it gracefully.

Can i call the application_close function defined in my application through the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Process.CloseMainWindow()` is what you're looking for, I believe.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.closemainwindow.aspx

**Edit**: If you really want to implement IPC, I've found utilizing [message queues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632590%28VS.85%29.aspx) to be the most easily-implemented solution in windows, but even that isn't very simple, and I wouldn't recommend it when all you want is resource cleanup on exit.

Comment: @Tanzelax that seems write, let me re-edit the question, is there someway i can call a function defined in the process, that does all house-keeping before closing the process

Comment: Whihle there isn't an easy way to call arbitrary code without actually implementing IPC, CloseMainWindow will essentially be the same as sending the alt-F4 to your windows app.  If your application has proper disposal handling in its main form's Dispose or whatever, that should be good enough for this usage.